# JAVA Need a condition to check whether the entire 2D array is full

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm making a game. In the game there is a grid that is populated by cells. Each cell has a partner (same type of cell). There should be 24 total cells which would mean 12 different pairs of cells. For example a cell can be type 1, there will be two type 1 cells on the grid.
All the way until type 12.
What I'm trying to achieve with my code is to randomly generate a row and column and then place a cell of type 1 on it. AGAIN, generate random row and column and place type 1 cell on it.
Then increment type.

Now what I am struggling with is the condition that will make sure my entire grid is fully populated with cells.
Further more a condition that makes sure that once a cell has been placed at a spot on the grid, it cannot be replaced by another cell.

Here is the code that I've come up with for now.

```
     int type =1;
    int row=0;
    int column=0;
    board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);



    while(board[row][column] != null){

      if(type <=12){



      row = generator.nextInt(4);
      column = generator.nextInt(6);      
      board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);
      type++;

        if (type < 13){
      row = generator.nextInt(4);      
      column = generator.nextInt(6);      
      board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);


      row = generator.nextInt(4);
      column = generator.nextInt(6);
      board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);


      add(board[row][column]);} //Adding a Cell object **board is a 2d array of type Cell**
      }
  }
  }
```

Tried my best to explain the problem in the most simple terms

Comment: Well if you're able to implement the condition for "making sure that once a cell has been placed at a spot on the grid, it cannot be replaced by another cell", then you would know for sure that the grid is full after exactly 12 iterations.

Comment: Yes, this is true. However I can't figure how to make sure that once a cell has been placed at a spot on the grid, it cannot be replaced by another cell."

Comment: Consider what a certain location `board[x][y]` looks like 1) Right after initialization, and 2) after a cell has been placed on it. You can then write a condition for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to do this than adding items at random would be to populate the array in a straightforward way and then randomise it, but there is no easy way to do that.

There is an equivalent thing you can do: create a `List` with all the required values in, [randomly `shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the `List` and then populate your array from that, mapping the entries in the List to the rows and columns on your array:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(24);

for (int type = 1; type <= 12; type++) {
  //Add each type twice
  list.add(type);
  list.add(type);
}

Collections.shuffle(list);
int[][] board = new int[4][6];

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
    int type = list.get(row + column * 4);
    board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);
  }
}
```

The mapping of rows and columns to List entries isn't all that important, as long as you use each entry from the shuffled List only once, so you could do this:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < 6; column++) {
    int type = i.next();
    board[row][column] = new Cell(this, type, row, column);
  }
}
```

Comment: So for the purpose of my problem i would have to instead of 
<Integer>, make it Cell.
Then my cell has a field called type that i would have to add into the list.
Board being an array of type Cell...I would then list.get(row+column * 4)

Comment: @Mjall2 - Yes, you're right. I have updated my sample code to match your question better.

Comment: Alright. So as I better understand the first block of code that does map the rows and columns. This would be because I understand the Collections.shuffle(list) statement. 
Thank you for your time! I hope to get this program done!

Comment: Just one more question sir,
int type = list.get(row + column * 4);
Why is there row + column * 4 and not just the first element in the list.

Comment: The second block of code only replaces the second half of the first block of code.  The thing is you want to make sure each element of the shuffled list is used only once when populating the array.  So you can map array entries to list entries using `row + column * 4` or you can work through the list using an `Iterator` or there are other ways you could do this too.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your board as a 1-D array indexed from 0 to 23. You can solve the problem by generating your pairs systematically and then assigning them to cells based on a random shuffle of the indexes.

This can be applied to a 2-D array by defining a mapping from [0...23] to the row and column indices:

```
row = index % 4;
column = index / 4;
```

(The inverse mapping is `index = column * 4 + row`, but you don't need that.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not exactly sure what index stands for. 
I understand that an array has a starting index of 0 and goes to 23 for a 24 slot array.

Comment: Orr, that was *my* answer ;) (+1 - shuffle a stack of indexes, draw cells from top and place types)

Comment: @Mjall2 - `index` was the index into [0...23]. It appears as the expression `row + column * 4` inside the loop of the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an algorithm like this. you can be sure after inserting max_array items, every cell is populated.

Note: No compiler, java-like pseudocode.

```
LinkedList<Long> freeCells = new LinkedHashSet<Long>();
for (int i = 0; i < max_x; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < max_y; ++j) {
        long idx = (((long) i) << 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
        idx = idx | ((long) j & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
        freeCells.add(idx);
    }
}
Random rand = new Random();
while (freeCells.size() > 0) {
    int r = rand.getNext() % freeCells.size();
    Long idx = freeCells.remove(r);
    int i = (int) ((idx >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
    int j = (int) (idx & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
    cell_matrix[i][j] = new Cell(type);
}
```

It's only a draft that should give you an idea of my intention.